# How can i fix this mongodb error?: MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'energy.$cond' is not valid for storage

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I get this error when i try to use the following code for mongoDB:

```js
var updateDoc = {
    $set: { 
        energy: { 
            $cond: { 
                if: { $gt: [ { $add: [ "$energy", 20 ] }, 100 ] }, 
                then: 100, 
                else: { $add: [ "$energy", 20 ] } 
            } 
        } 
    }
  }
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is a aggregation operator, update can't allow that operator in this simple query,

Look at the [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

You just need to wrap `updateDoc` object in to array,

```
var updateDoc = [
  {
    $set: {
      energy: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $gt: [{ $add: ["$energy", 20] }, 100] },
          then: 100,
          else: { $add: ["$energy", 20] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vstMp2es3Mx)